# WebView Post on Android (preferably Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, webview

Trying to post to a web view in Android. I need to pass in headers (username, password, contentType) **AND** body parameters. Currently I see `webView.LoadUrl` takes in the url and headers however I do not see any options for loading a url with body and headers. Just for reference Im trying to achieve something similar to this, which works perfectly in iOS:

```
public void OpenWebPage(ReviewWebRequest request)
        {
            var nsRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest
            {
                Url = new NSUrl(request.Url),
                HttpMethod = request.Method
            };

            var nsHeaders = request.Headers;
            nsRequest.Headers = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(nsHeaders.Values.ToArray(), nsHeaders.Keys.ToArray());
            nsRequest.Body = NSData.FromString(request.BodyString, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
            webView.LoadRequest(nsRequest);
        }
```

Comment: Xamarin.Android only surfaces what the native Android SDK provides, so since the Android WebView does not seem to offer the same functionality that iOS does, you will need to find another solution.

Comment: That was my question. What are the other solutions? I cant see to find anything to work, including intercepting and/or overriding the request